# Distribution of maximum of random variables taken over an uncountable set

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and a one-dimensional Wiener process (Brownian motion) $\{W_t\}_{t\in [0,\infty)}$ adapted to its natural filtration. By Wiener process I mean that $\{W_t\}_{t\in [0,\infty)}$  fulfils following properties

1. $P(\{\omega:W_0(\omega) = 0\}) = 1$
2. $\forall t_0,t_1,...,t_n \in [0,\infty): t_0 \le t_1 \le ... \le t_n$ we have that $W_{t_0}, W_{t_1}-W_{t_0}, ..., W_{t_n} - W_{t_{n-1}}$ are independent
3. $\forall s \in [0,t): W_t - W_s \sim N(0,t-s)$
4. $P(\{\omega: t \mapsto W_t(\omega) - \textrm{continuous}\}) = 1$

Now I consider sequence of random variables defined as follows $Y_n = \max_{s \in [n,n+1]}\frac{\vert W_{n+1}-W_{s} \vert}{n}$.
I suspect that distribution of $Y_n$ is the same as $Y_1$ multiplied by $\frac{1}{n}$ but I was not able to formally prove it. My question is how to directly calculate the distribution of $Y_n$, considering that maximum function ranges over a unit interval? I would be grateful for some hints.

Comment: Your $Y_n$ is going to have the same distribution as $\frac1n Y_1$ and $Y_1$ has the same distribution as $\max\limits_{t \in [0,1]}\vert W_{t} \vert$

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356903/running-maximum-absolute-value-of-wiener-process/1077795) can be useful.

Comment: @Henry And does$\textrm{Var}(\vert W_t \vert) < \infty$ for each $t\in [0,1]$ imply $\textrm{Var}(Y_1) < \infty$?

Comment: @MI97 [An answer to a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3126708/6460) suggests that the tail of the distribution is not heavy so I would expect $\textrm{Var}(Y_1)$ to be finite